# Message Box show error when the code does not have message box show

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I get the following error when I am running my asp.net website from a live site.  When I run it locally, I do not get any errors.  I do not have anything in the vb.net code side for a message box.  I have searched the entire project for it, and I do not have it in my application.  I did use msgbox("") during testing, but removed it before uploading.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.]
>      System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp) +2994248
>      Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Object Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons, Object Title) +526
>      InventoryManagement.WebForm2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users*****\Documents\Manageinfo.aspx.vb:62
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>      System.Web.UI.d__1.MoveNext() +230
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      System.Web.Util.WithinCancellableCallbackTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +31
>      System.Web.UI.d__1.MoveNext() +4866
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0
>
> InventoryManagement.WebForm2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users*****\Documents\Manageinfo.aspx.vb:62 is a blank line.

I tried commenting out the entire Manageinfo.aspx.vb except for the class, and I am still getting the error. I have cleared out my cache, tried Internet explorer, and Microsoft Edge.  Also I have had another person I know try it from there computer with the same error.  I am now trying to figure out if my host caches the sites.

Thanks in advance!
Russell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if during your website upload (or Publish) the "delete found files" is checked - or something like this.

In past, when I had been working in ASP.NET files, I had seen that even newer files were discarded from publishing only because old versions were in website. I remember you have an option to force the deletion (not the replace) of existing files.

And yu can also CLEAN and BUILD the project instead REBUILD. Sometimes it helps too.

Good luck.

Comment: This did not solve the issue.  I am positive its going to be the web host, but it was the most informational post!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @russnbhs, thanks for your vote. Anyway, this tip is usefull for some other problems you could have in future. Best wishes, good luck.

Comment: I want to correct my original response to this.  The solution did not sink in until I researched the publish feature.  The publish feature was not on my menu bar, after researching I found it.  I had not worked with asp.net for about 2 years, and didnt even think that not using the publish feature would impact it.  I was copying over all the files, which I know is a big mistake!!  Your answer actually fixed the problem!  After using the publish feature, I am now up and running the way it should be!  Thanks for your help!  I am a desktop vb.net developer not asp.net!  Thanks again!!

Comment: I´m glad you solved the problem with my tip. Just remember to help someone in the future if he face the same problem. Kindest regards.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `Page_Load()` method in this file, as shown in your stack trace:

> C:\Users*****\Documents\Manageinfo.aspx.vb:62

Line 62 on that file is still calling `MsgBox()`. If you don't see it in your code, upload again, because the server is likely running an old version.

Comment: I have uploaded multiple times.  Line 62 is blank.  I tried to get in touch with my hosting company, and it is time for a new one.  I was on hold for about 2 hrs before finally saying screw it, I'll start over.  I am guessing the hosting company is caching the web sites.